# JQuery/JQuery mobile page height issue with safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I'm trying to code a simple html page with a JQuery-mobile header and a map (using nokia here map api).

I want the map to fit the whole screen, so I tried to compute its height by taking the screen height and then subtracting the header height. After some attempts to get the right size, the result is good on every browser I tried except on Safari for Ipad: with the latter, the map has the right size, but the page can scroll a little if you touch the header and you can see about ten "extra pixels".

Here's the code (I have omitted the script to load the map):

```
<div id="home" data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h3>HEADER</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-solo" id="map">
        <div class="ui-block-a" id="bigMapContainer">   
        </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>


$(window).resize(function (){

    var maxWidth = $(window).width();
    var maxHeight = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();

    var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
    var mapHeight = maxHeight - headerHeight;
    $('#map').css("height",mapHeight);

});

$(document).ready(function () {

    var maxWidth = $(window).width();
    var maxHeight = $.mobile.getScreenHeight();

    var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight(true);
    var mapHeight = maxHeight - headerHeight;
    $('#map').css("height",mapHeight);

});
```

I'm really getting crazy with this issue, since I really doesn't understand why the other browser seem to perform well the code. Does anyone has some tips?

Comment: try setting data-tap-toggle="false" on the header and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help...I wonder why it gives this error only on Safari. I tried other browser and everything's ok!

Comment: @ezanker alternatively, how can I avoid the page to scroll? I know this is not the right way to solve the issue, but I'm really stucked here

Comment: Have a look at Omar's solution: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/  Fixed headers have an extra pixel and the content should be sized, then the map can be set to 100% width and height....

Comment: Nothing...I have tested Omar's solution, but I still have the same issue on Safari mobile...

Comment: are you testing it on iPad 2 iOS 7?

Comment: no, it's iPad 3 iOS 7